# SQL: Update a column after a specific number of days

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that lists the bugs along with the info regarding to who it was assigned and who resolved it.

```
Bugs | Assigned to | Resolved by
--------------------------------
  1       Dev1 
  2       Dev2
  3       Dev3
```

If after a specific number of days (for e.g., 14 days), if the field 'Resolved by' is still blank, I want it to be updated with the value from the column 'Assigned to'.

I was trying to create a view with a time stamp but I'm not sure how to specify the exact number of days and then update the value from another column.

Comment: Presumably you have a date/time column of when the column was created.

Comment: Why not schedule a daily job to update any rows that match your rule? This seems like an odd requirement though - you're effectively closing bugs with no evidence they've even been investigated.

Comment: you can make resolved by as computed column.

Comment: But, what if that specific bug hasn't been resolved in *specific number of days* but is still open and waits to be fixed? Won't that - what you're trying to do - be misleading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a view with something like this:

```
create view v_bugs as
    select bugs, assigned_to,
           coalesce(resolved_by,
                    (case when createdAt <= sysdate - interval '14' day then assigned_to end)
                   ) as assigned_to
    from bugs;
```

This assumes, of course, that you have a column that specifies when  each row was inserted.

Unfortunately, Oracle does not allow `sysdate` in a virtual column, so you cannot use `generated always as` to define the column.